# Creating a ToolTip Managed bean

Tags: xpages, managed-bean

This is a followup to my previous post at [ToolTip Performance in XPages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461475/tooltip-performance-in-xpages) I have got the code to do it written (not tested) so I can't seem to get my Managed Bean to get called properly. My config contians the following:

```
<managed-bean id="ToolTip">
<managed-bean-name>WFSToolTip</managed-bean-name>
<managed-bean-class>ca.workflo.wfsToolTip.ToolTipText</managed-bean-class>
<managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

and I have stripped my code down to the bare minimum:

```
package ca.workflo.wfsToolTip;

public class ToolTipText   {

    public String getToolTipText(String key){
        return key;
    }
}
```

My class is in the build path. I have a simple XPage with one filed on it and a tool tip for that field. The code for the tooltip is:

```
<xe:tooltip id="tooltip1" for="inputText1">
<xe:this.label>
<![CDATA[#{javascript:WFSToolTip.getToolTipText("More Stuff");}]]>
</xe:this.label>
</xe:tooltip>
```

When I load the test XPage in the browser I get an error that:

Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Script interpreter error, line=1, col=12: Error calling method 'getToolTipText(string)' on java class 'ca.workflo.wfsToolTip.ToolTipText'

JavaScript code

1: WFSToolTip.getToolTipText("More Stuff");

I can't figure out why the call to getToolTipText would fail.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong. This is my first Managed Bean and at the moment it is managing me rather than the other way around.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to:
- implement Serializable which boils down to state it and provide a version
- implement Map ... a little more work

Then you use Expression Language instead of SSJS. It would look like `#{WFSToolTip["More Stuff"]}`

This is how such a class would look like. You need to:

- adjust the view name to reflect the name you want
- the view needs to be flat, column 1 = tooltip name, column 2 = tooltip text
- somewhere (on an admin/config page) you need to call `WFSToolTip.clear();` (in SSJS) after you update the values in the configuration.

The example doesn't lazyload since running though a view navigator once is really fast. No point to do all these lookups.

Here you go:

```
package com.notessensei.xpages;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Vector;

import lotus.domino.Base;
import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.View;
import lotus.domino.ViewEntry;
import lotus.domino.ViewEntryCollection;

import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil;

public class Parameters implements Serializable, Map<String, String> {

    private final static String       CONFIG_VIEW      = "keywords";

    private static final long         serialVersionUID  = 1L;
    private final Map<String, String>   internalMap    = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public Parameters() {
        this.populateParameters(internalMap);
    }

    private void populateParameters(Map<String, String> theMap) {

        Database d = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentDatabase();
        try {
            View v = d.getView(CONFIG_VIEW);
            ViewEntryCollection vec = v.getAllEntries();
            ViewEntry ve = vec.getFirstEntry();
            ViewEntry nextVe = null;

            while (ve != null) {
                nextVe = vec.getNextEntry(ve);
                // Load the parameters, column 0 is the key, column 0 the value
                Vector colVal = ve.getColumnValues();
                theMap.put(colVal.get(0).toString(), colVal.get(1).toString());
                // Cleanup
                this.shred(ve);
                ve = nextVe;
            }
            // recycle, but not the current database!!!
            this.shred(ve, nextVe, vec, v); 
        } catch (NotesException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        this.internalMap.clear();
        this.populateParameters(this.internalMap);
    }

    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return this.internalMap.containsKey(key);
    }

    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return this.internalMap.containsValue(value);
    }

    public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<String, String>> entrySet() {
        return this.internalMap.entrySet();
    }

    public String get(Object key) {
        return this.internalMap.get(key);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.internalMap.isEmpty();
    }

    public Set<String> keySet() {
        return this.internalMap.keySet();
    }

    public String put(String key, String value) {
        return this.internalMap.put(key, value);
    }

    public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends String> m) {
        this.internalMap.putAll(m);
    }

    public String remove(Object key) {
        return this.internalMap.remove(key);
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.internalMap.size();
    }

    public Collection<String> values() {
        return this.internalMap.values();
    }

    private void shred(Base... morituri) {

        for (Base obsoleteObject : morituri) {
            if (obsoleteObject != null) {
                try {
                    obsoleteObject.recycle();
                } catch (NotesException e) {
                    // We don't care we want go get
                    // rid of it anyway
                } finally {
                    obsoleteObject = null;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The difference to a regular HashMap is only the constructor that populates it. Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Wouldn't that EL try to call a getter for "More Stuff"? I still use SSJS for method calls, so #{WFSToolTip.getToolTipText("More Stuff");}. The only caveat I've found is I think you're creating an instance of a JavaScript object - so a JavaScript String - which needs to be converted to the Java object - a Java String. Normally that's fine, but some data types can catch you out, like numbers.

Comment: When your Java object implements the Map interface WFSToolTip["More Stuff"] will call the Map.get("More Stuff") method.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. That's why to implement Map as well as Serializable.

Comment: ummm wow.  I don't totally get it but I think the whole "implement Map" thing and EL ramification is an extremely interesting concept.  Other then MAYBE in one of Tim's NotesIn9 videos I've never seen that done before....

Comment: It is something that invites all sorts of sneaky things. Just imagine the map returns not a String, but a Map again you can do interesting things like Invoice["12342"]["Total"]

Comment: Of course WFSToolTip.getToolTipText("More Stuff"); in the will not work because a get can not pass a value. This is not a Bean with getters and setters I changed the method to findToolTipText and the call to WFSToolTip.findToolTipText("More Stuff") and that works. The passed value is going to be used as a key to look up a returned String Value to be displayed in the calling ToolTip. So I'm not sure I see how the #{WFSToolTip["My Lookup Key"]} would know what to do.
Please excuse my ignorance but this is my first attempt at a Bean. Once into it I have the code to load the TreeMap figured out.

Comment: @stwissel - Thank you so much for your post. I think I understand how it works! I don't think I would have figured it out without your help. I will re-write my code in the light of what you posted and make it work in my situation. again Thank you Thank you Thank you! I think with this and the other research that I have done will get me started on JAVA and I emphasize the STARTED

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that id property..  My beans in faces-config look like this:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>CurrentJob</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.domain.inventory.Job</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Technically managed beans should implement Serializable and have a blank constructor.  So you should have something like this inside :

```
public ToolTipText() {

}
```

I THINK you can get away without the Serializable for somethings...  I always implement though but I'm sure you need the no argument constructor.

Comment: David - I got the <managed-bean id="ToolTip"> from the config of the debuToolBar and just included it in mine. Stephan Whissel's posted code has really helped and I've almost got my code working. If it works the way I want it to it should really speed up the ExtLib ToolTip. I had to take the ToolTips off of a very large XPage that really needs the context sensitive help of the ToolTip but it was painfully slow. I found that each tooltip was doing the lookup to the Help database multiple times in a single session. This would make a greate NotesIn9 video.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all that have responded and helped out here especially Stephan Wissel. I thought I would post my version of Stephan's code, pretty much the same. There are issues with making the class an ApplicationScope because you need to shut down the HTTP task to refresh and reload the Class. What I did was added a button to the custom control where I to the view of the tooltips where I do the CRUD stuff and in the button do WFSToolTip().clear() and it rebuilds the map. Pretty neat. My next task for this is try to do the CRUD using JAVA and update the map directly. At the moment though I need to move on to my next task.
My next task revolves around a very similar Class. I have a master database that contains all the basic design and code. Then I have one or more applications that use that code and store the documents in their own database that contains the forms and views for that specific application. In the master I have created one or more application documents. Each of these documents contains the AppName (the key value) then the Map value is an array (Vector) containing the ReplicaID of the Application Database and a few other pieces of information. My class the loads a Map entry for each Application and collects a bunch of other information about the application from several places and stores that in the Map Value. At this point then I can set Database db = thisClass.getDatabase("App Name"). so a single custom control can be used for any/all of the applications. Pretty cool. I think I could get to like this.
Anyway here is the code I'm using for the ToolTips - BTW It has taken an XPage with about 175 fields and 100+ tooltips from being painfully slow to being acceptable. The good thing about it is that the XPage is creating a process profile document and once created it is not frequently modified as an admin action - not an everyday user action.
Please feel free point out error, omitions or suggestions to the code:

```
package ca.workflo.wfsToolTip;

import lotus.domino.Base;
import lotus.domino.Session;
import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.View;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.ViewEntry;
import lotus.domino.ViewEntryCollection;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Vector;

import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil;

public class ToolTipText implements Serializable, Map<String, String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Session s;
    private String repID;
    private Database db;
    private Database helpDB;
    private View helpView;
    private ViewEntry ve;
    private ViewEntry tVE;
    private ViewEntryCollection veCol;
    private final Map<String, String> internalMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ToolTipText() {
        this.populateMap(internalMap);
    }

    private void populateMap(Map<String, String> theMap) {

        try {
            s = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession();
            db = s.getCurrentDatabase();
            repID = db.getProfileDocument("frmConfigProfile", "").getItemValue(
                    "WFSHelpRepID").firstElement().toString();
            helpDB = s.getDbDirectory(null).openDatabaseByReplicaID(repID);
            helpView = helpDB.getView("vwWFSToolTipHelp");
            veCol = helpView.getAllEntries();
            ve = veCol.getFirstEntry();
            ViewEntry tVE = null;
            while (ve != null) {
                tVE = veCol.getNextEntry(ve);
                Vector colVal = ve.getColumnValues();
                theMap.put(colVal.get(0).toString(), colVal.get(1).toString());
                recycleObjects(ve);
                ve = tVE;
            }
        } catch (NotesException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }finally{
            recycleObjects(ve, tVE, veCol, helpView, helpDB);
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        this.internalMap.clear();
        this.populateMap(this.internalMap);
    }

    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return this.internalMap.containsKey(key);
    }

    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return this.internalMap.containsValue(value);
    }

    public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<String, String>> entrySet() {
        return this.internalMap.entrySet();
    }

    public String get(Object key) {
        try {
            if (this.internalMap.containsKey(key)) {
                return this.internalMap.get(key);
            } else {
                return "There is no Tooltip Help for " + key;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "error in tooltip get Object ";
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.internalMap.isEmpty();
    }

    public Set<String> keySet() {
        return this.internalMap.keySet();
    }

    public String put(String key, String value) {
        return this.internalMap.put(key, value);
    }

    public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends String> m) {
        this.internalMap.putAll(m);
    }

    public String remove(Object key) {
        return this.internalMap.remove(key);
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.internalMap.size();
    }

    public Collection<String> values() {
        return this.internalMap.values();
    }

    public static void recycleObjects(Object... args) {
        for (Object o : args) {
            if (o != null) {
                if (o instanceof Base) {
                    try {
                        ((Base) o).recycle();
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        // who cares?
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```