# Managed-Bean best practice

Tags: java, xpages

I'm back to building my Managed-Bean of a hashMap. ( [Creating a HashMap of type <String , Object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663619/creating-a-hashmap-of-type-string-object) ) I have defined a class

```
public class AppProperties {
    private String appRepID;
    private String helpRepID;
    private String ruleRepID;
    private String filePath;
    private Vector formNames;
    private Database appDB;
    // all the getters and setters
}
```

The managed bean will create an Application Scope variable of the hashMap. In the constructor of the Bean I build the the values for each Application (the key) by collecting all the info from a number of different places. The repIDs are pretty straight forward. My question/concern is it wise to store the appBD in the Application Scope variable. I have read that one should never store a Notes Object in a Scoped Variable would that be an issue here? Secondly, if that is the case I could add a method to the AppProperties that would open the DatabaseByReplicaID when ever the method to get the Application Database is called, which adds a fair bit of overhead to the process as the database object will get called many many time in the life cycle of the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right, you shouldn't store Notes objects in scope variables and properties of beans.

Because They are not serializable (a must for certain scopes) and they will be recycled between lifecycles. More precisely, since they are based on C-handles, XSP engine creates Notes objects between request-response cycle and when response written back to the user, they are all going to be recycled. Trying to keep them in the memory will make them 'toxic' for your server.

You can define a method in your bean (like GetHelpDb()), create and return it whenever you need. It's not a huge performance cost. Because Domino server implements caching for databases. When you open a database over and over again will not generate additional disk I/O.

The best practice for interacting with Notes data in such situation would be caching. I frequently use this approach in my applications. You might get values in a single method, cache them into HashMap(s) and get them from the map when you need. Using getter method, you may also check a time-based value to handle time-outs.

Comment: Also the bean has to implement java.io.Serializable, because you need to store values between requests and get them again

Comment: @Paul - Yes my Bean does that, my class AppProperties does not but it is imported into the Bean that is serialized, so I would assume at that point the class AppProperties would be serialized by the Bean.

Comment: Yes. It should be serialized if it's going to be imported into a serialized object.

Comment: You can use NotesObjects as properties of your bean if you mark them as transient, and then make the getter lazy load it.
transient modifier means 'don't serialize this one'. Once you bean is reconstructed, it will be null, and the first call to the getter can reinitialize it

Comment: Yes, transient fields can be used to be able to store objects that should not be serialized within serialized classes. However, it's only useful in viewscope. Because other scopes are not serialized and transient objects will persist in the memory. Notes objects should not persist in any way.